# How to include a beginning AND end in an audio file in html?

Tags: html, audio, delimited

I'm trying to add several audio files with very precise beginnings and ends. I'm not an html expert, but so far the best and simplest formula I've found is

#t=262,302

That works fine (with Chrome) for the beginning mark (262), but not the end (302). Instead, it plays all the way to the end of the entire file.

Any idea how I can stop it at the 302 mark (in this case)?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

See above. Tried #t=262,302. The result: it started fine at 262, but didn't stop at 302.

Answer (score 0):

add another #t like this `#t=262,302#t=,302"`  this should ensure that the audio file stops at the correct time.

Comment: Thank you so much Charfeddine, but that didn't work. I tried every possible iteration, but nothing seems to work. They all end up playing the .mp3 from the very beginning. The only one that works where I want it (at the 33 mark) is ... .mp3#t=33. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a follow up, it looks like a simple formula works: #t=262,302 . Yes, a simple coma between the two numbers. What threw me off was that when that segment is played, it shows the opening number, but instead of showing as well the closing number, it shows the number of the end of the .mp3 file. Odd.  If anyone has any idea why that is and how to correct it, I would be grateful. Thank you.